# Set an external variable from another Python script

Tags: python

I am going to try to be clear. I have a `ex.py` file I want to import in other `py` files. In the `ex.py` file there is a variable that I declare. However, I would like to declare that variable in the other `py` files.

I have a file `ex.py`:

```
variable = 5
whatever = 10 + variable
```

For example in an other `.py` file, I would have:

```
from ex import whatever
variable = 10
print(whatever)  # whatever object uses the variable
```

The result from printing `whatever` will be `15`. I would like to have `20` as i declare `variable` in the new script.

That is to streamline the code so that the same `.py` file can be used in several other files.
Any contribution please.

Comment: What would be the contents of `ex.py` and what is the expected output of `print(whatever)`?

Comment: Your code looks fine, as far as it goes. What's the problem?

Comment: @metatoaster i have edited

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want `whatever` to always be `variable + 5`, right? If you set `whatever` in the `ex.py`, its value is fixed to 15 and will not change.
In this case you should declare a function which calculates `whatever` dynamically, like so:

```
def whatever(variable):
  return variable + 5
```

If you want to have multiple .py files accessing the same global variable (the other interpretation of your question I can come up with), you might want to have a look at [the singleton pattern](https://python-3-patterns-idioms-test.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Singleton.html)

Comment: your comment is very useful. however, i am not sure it is the correct answer. I want `whatever` to always be `variable + 10` in that case. `variable` from the new `.py` file + `10` from the `ex.py` file.

Comment: @delalma It's not possible to make a variable change automatically like that. There's no way to link variables. If you want something to calculate dynamically, you need a function.